# QT exec() command crash

Tags: c++, matlab, qt, qt4, mex

I´m developing an application in QT 4.7.3. This application is called from Matlab(simulink) using a mexFunction (*.mexw32)

When I try to open a dialog using **dialog.exec()** command, the form is displayed but I get a **"non responding application"** instantaneously. After that, matlab crashes.

If i try to open the dialog using **dialog.show()** command, it works fine.

I really have no idea of whats going on, since both commands are somehow similar, as [described here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/38370-QDialog-exec()-exiting-without-calling-QDialog-accept())

Does anyone know what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dialog.exec()` spins a local event loop that doesn't integrate well with the one that Matlab itself is spinning. Thus the crash. Conversely, you're banking on Matlab doing the right thing as far as its own event loop being compatible with Qt's requirements goes. This doesn't hold on all platforms, unfortunately, although on Windows it seems to work.

You should never be using `exec()` outside of `main` anyway.

Comment: What are my options, since I need to wait the user input?

Comment: Waiting has no place in modern async UI code. Connect to the dialog's `accepted` or `rejected` signals to run your slot/functor when the dialog is accepted/rejected.

Comment: Just to confirm: I cannot use something like this QMessageBox::question(...). Is that correct?

What is strange is that this messagebox works in my colleague PC but crashes in mine, with both running the same hardware/software

Comment: @guilhermecgs These "convenience" apis are sadly broken, since they only expose the pseudo-synhronous interface. You'll need to write your own convenience wrappers by copy-pasting the Qt code, and removing the `exec()` call. Takes a minute and solves the problem. The wrapper can even `show()` the dialog for you. It can even take a functor to call to pass the results to.