# QT signal slot not working

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qt4.7

Why this code does not call the desired slot?

I have trying to make it work for the last 3 hours!

```
void TForm::on_clicked( bool checked )
{
    QMessageBox *messageBox = new QMessageBox(this);
    QPushButton *buttonAccept0 = new QPushButton("OK", messageBox);
    QPushButton *buttonReject = new QPushButton("Cancel", messageBox);
    messageBox->addButton(buttonAccept0, QMessageBox::ButtonRole::AcceptRole);
    messageBox->addButton(buttonReject, QMessageBox::ButtonRole::NoRole);
    messageBox->setWindowTitle("Confirmation");
    messageBox->setText("Remove?");
    messageBox->setModal(true);
    messageBox->show(); 
    QObject::connect(buttonAccept0, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(a1()));
}
void TForm::a1()
{
    std::string ff = "";
}
```

Comment: `QPushButton` does not have a signal called `accepted()`.  You should have seen a warning message about this when running your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things worth noting about your question:

---

Firstly, your error is as a result of you using the incorrect signal (as other members have already mentioned).

To correct your error, make the following change to your code:

```
QObject::connect(buttonAccept0, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(at()));
```

---

Secondly, unlike @M74 mentioned in his/her answer, it is perfectly allowed to declare the message box and the signals inside the `on_clicked` function. The reason @M74 is concerned is because of potential memory leaks but Qt has a mechanism for overcoming that in the form of parenting, which you did correctly when you defined the messagebox at the beginning of the function.

Unfortunately, @M74's concerns are not entirely unfounded since the messagebox will only be destroyed when the parent is destroyed.

If your instance of `TForm` remains alive for the entire time of the application, and you execute `on_clicked` many times, you will have many instances of the messageBox created and waiting in the background to be deleted, a kind of memory leak in itself.

A better way of avoiding this would be to modify your code to make the `messageBox` a stack variable, local to the function. The two `QPushButton` instances can still be created in heap memory since they will be automatically destroyed when the messagebox is destroyed, once again because of parenting.

```
void TForm::on_clicked(bool checked)
{
    QMessageBox messageBox;
    QPushButton *buttonAccept0 = new QPushButton("Ok", &messageBox);
    QPushButton *buttonReject = new QPushButton("Cancel", &messageBox);
    messageBox.addButton(buttonAccept0, QMessageBox::AcceptRole);
    messageBox.addButton(buttonReject, MessageBox::NoRole);
    messageBox.setWindowTitle("Confirmation");
    messageBox.setText("Remove?");
    messageBox.setModal(true);
    connect(buttonAccept0, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(a1()));
    messageBox.show();
}
```

Note:

1. It is generally a good idea to set up all your connections before displaying your dialog boxes, in case a signal fires before you've made the connection. This is why I moved the `show` statement to last.
2. You can replace the two statements:

   `messageBox.setModal(true);`

   `messageBox.show();`

with

```
    messageBox.exec();
```

the result will be the same.

---

Lastly,

`QMessageBox` comes with a number of static functions for common purposes. The code that is shown in the question fits perfectly into one of the standard use-cases so everything can be rewritten using the following:

```
if (QMessageBox::question(nullptr, "Confirmation", "Remove?", 
    QMessageBox::Ok | QMessageBox::Cancel, 
    QMessageBox::Cancel) == QMessageBox::Ok)
{
    a1();
}
```

Comment: HI @RobbieE, great answer, really. Thank you for helping. It worked just fine.  About your final comment, the reason I´m not using the  static functions is because they somehow crash the application when I call exec() not in main thread. I have already asked a question before (  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548664/qt-exec-command-crash ). If you have other alternatives, please share with me! :-)

Comment: You are not allowed to use GUI classes in secondary threads, only the main thread.

Comment: The statement that `exec()` and `show()` are equivalent is horribly misleading. `exec()` does not belong in quality code, except to start an event loop in a thread that doesn't have one yet, and for the `QDrag` bastard. Otherwise, it results in pseudo-synchronous spaghetti. Please, do not encourage anyone to replace `show()` with `exec()`!

Comment: @KubaOber I agree for the most part, but what I think what he meant was that they are equivalent *functionally* speaking. They both block the GUI thread and show.

Comment: @ArnabDatta `show()` doesn't block. It returns immediately to the caller.

Comment: @KubaOber So the combination of setModal(true) and show() will not block the GUI thread?

Comment: @ArnabDatta No, it won't. Window modality and blocking are two separate things. When you show an application modal window, you merely prevent other top-level widgets (windows) from receiving user input. They still receive all other events and simply act as if the user wasn't interacting with them.